# How do I get a json list of REST SOE's supported by a Mapservice?

Tags: arcgis-server, rest, server-object-extension

The html returned by a rest [mapservice url](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/mapserver.html) includes "supported extensions" down at the bottom.  However the json returned does not list the extensions.  Is there a way to get this list of SOE's in a json format?

I'd include a sample url, but I can't find any rest SOE's when I search - does anyone know of a sample that has been published?

**Update**
Thanks to Bill, here's an ESRI sample that illustrates the issue:
The [html page](http://sampleserver4.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Elevation/ESRI_Elevation_World/MapServer) returns Supported Extensions, but when formatted [as json](http://sampleserver4.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Elevation/ESRI_Elevation_World/MapServer?f=pjson), it doesn't.

**Update 2**
ESRI support filed it as an enhance request (NIM062551).

Comment: There is a sample with a REST SOE here: http://sampleserver4.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Elevation/ESRI_Elevation_World/MapServer but I don't see the "ElevationsSOE" included in the JSON response.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I'll report this to ESRI.  I wonder why google doesn't find the html page for this mapservice http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=Supported+Extensions+++ElevationsSOE+&aq=f&aqi=m1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=CbXIo4tPSTIqtJ4PuMJeL7NgPAAAAqgQFT9C6BLo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how to do it. The REST API documentation discusses how to get information about SOEs as child resources of a MapServer (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/index.html?admin.html). Logic would indicate that {MapServer URL}/exts should return a list of SOEs but it returns an error. Only when you specifically call down to the SOE resource do you get a response.

To me, this seems to be a gap in the API. If you know of a specific SOE, you can get information about it, but I don't see any way to get a list of available SOEs in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to do something <strike>absolutely</strike> moderately awful, you **could** get the contents of that page as HTML, and then use jQuery to get the links:

```
var extAnchors = $('b').filter( function( index ) { 
   if( this.innerHTML.match( 'Supported Extensions' ) ) 
      return true; 
   } ).nextAll('a');
```

This gets all the anchor elements after the phrase "Supported Extensions". You'd at least have something to work with until ESRI patches the API.

I'll see if I can come up with an equivalent for use with Dojo, which I like about 100 times less than jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Herb.  Right now I'm really just needing to know if a mapservice has a particular SOE - not a list of all soe's.  I will need that eventually.  But for now, since I'm using WPF, I think I'll just using webclient to see if a rest error json string is returned for the soe's expected url.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one alternative approach would to be implement another REST SOE which would provide a JSON list of other enabled extensions.

You can use the [IServerObjectExtensionManager](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/003z/003z000000qn000000.htm) interface for that, but this of course assumes you know the names or GUIDs of all the registered extensions, since as far as I know, there is no way to access [IServerObjectConfiguration3](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//003z000000nq000000) or [IServerObjectManager2.GetExtensionTypeInfos](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//003z000000s2000000) from within your SOE, which would be helpful.